# Finding frequency of maximum digit in a number

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i=0,max=0;
    long long int n,p;
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    while(n>0)
    {
        p=n%10;
        if(p==max)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else if(p>max)
        {
            max=p;
            i=1;
        }
        n/=10;
    }
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

The code gives correct results for numbers like **8687557576676885** . But for the input **11111111111111111111111111111111** , it doesn't give the proper result . I've seen similar problem in this site but those were written in different language. I want to know where the problem lies for large number .

Thanks...

**N.B. :** It would be helpful if anyone could give alternate solutions . I'm still a newbie,so it would help me to understand things more deeply.

Comment: Why not treat it like a string, not an integer? Same idea, just looking at a character at a time.

Comment: you overflow your `long long` with _11111111111111111111111111111111_ , look at my answer

Comment: @Shawn .. I'm able to do it with string. Now I'm trying it this way, but not  happening

Comment: @NehalSamee I give a way working on the string (in fact reading character per character) in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code gives correct results for numbers like 8687557576676885 . But for the input 11111111111111111111111111111111

*8687557576676885* requires 53 bits but *11111111111111111111111111111111* need 104 bits, too much for your *long long* probably on 64bits

> It would be helpful if anyone could give alternate solutions

Rather than to use *scanf* use *fgets* or equivalent then *strtoll* and you will be able to detect the overflow looking at *errno*

However in your case you do not need to extract the number, just work on the string, for instance to not be limited by any size :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i=0,max=-1;
  int c;

  while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) && (c != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
    if ((c < '0') || (c > '9')) {
      printf("'%c' is not a valid digit\n", c);
      return -1;
    }
    c -= '0';
    if(c==max)
    {
      i++;
    }
    else if(c>max)
    {
      max=c;
      i=1;
    }
  }
  if (max != -1)
    printf("%d times %d\n",i, max);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
8687557576676885
4 times 8
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
42 times 1
```

Comment: can you elaborate **c-='0';** ?

Comment: @NehalSamee that transforms the code of a digit character to its value, so '0' -> 0, '1' -> 1 etc because whatever the code followed by the compiler (ASCII or an other) the language guaranty that '0' +1 is '1', and '0'  + 2 is '2' etc up to '0' + 9 is '9', so on the reverse for instance '5' - '0' is 5

Answer (score 1):

There is an overflow in your code.  I printed the value read by scanf and the result is so:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
7 0 922337203685477580
0 7 92233720368547758
8 7 9223372036854775
5 8 922337203685477
7 8 92233720368547
7 8 9223372036854
4 8 922337203685
5 8 92233720368
8 8 9223372036
6 8 922337203
3 8 92233720
0 8 9223372
2 8 922337
7 8 92233
3 8 9223
3 8 922
2 8 92
2 8 9
9 8 0
9 1
```

I used this modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int count=0,max=0, digit;
  long long int n;
  scanf("%lld",&n);
  while(n)
  {
    digit=n%10,n/=10;
    printf("%d %d %lld\n",digit, max, n);
    if(digit==max)
      count++;
    else if(digit>max)
      max=digit,
      count=1;
  }
  printf("%d %d",max, count);
  return 0;
}
```

In order to avoid the overflow you need to read the number as a string `char*number` and treat digits as characters. You should do it so:

```
int main(void)
{
  int count=0;
  char max='0', digit;
  char n[1000], *p=n;
  fgets(n, 1000, stdin);
  while(*p)
    {
      digit=*p++;
      if(digit==max)
        count++;
      else if(digit>max)
        max=digit,
        count=1;
    }
  printf("%c %d",max, count);
  return 0;
}
```